# Silverstripe and BSD license situation

Tags: open-source, silverstripe

I have situation where developer claims that website which she is working for my firm is based on opensource CMS/framework Silverstripe. Second claim is that he want his code to be implemented on machine where I dont have access. In addition I have possibility to switch domain on/off from IP he provided me. I can't see actually what he coded and what is feature of cms.

My question is: Is that situation usual? And what are my rights as customer according to BSD licence? Can I view the code he is coding? Especially i have impression that he is renting software to me in that way. But want to be paid in terms of architect and develope hours. Can someone clarify situation to me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the [license](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework#license) is pretty clear: As long as you keep the copyright notice, you can do whatever you want (change, sell,...).

So what your developer is doing, is ok in terms of the SilverStripe license. The rest is up to your contract.

Is it usual? While I would try to avoid this and it's probably not the norm, it's hardly unusual. However, you are bound to the developer in the future, which might lead to problems:

- "Change developer? Sure you can — if you start from scratch again."
- "My rate just went up, but I'm sure it's cheaper than starting over."

Answer (score 2):

It is "usual" for a developer to take advantage of open source components - in fact, there are many advantages of using proven open source components instead of building them from scratch (e.g. speed up the development, widely used open source component can be pretty robust etc).

You do need to make sure there isn't any licensing concerns, but in this particular case, you should be fine with BSD license, as it is one of the most permissive license out there.  All you need to do is meet its attribution requirements (essentially including the original copyright and license text in tact).

RE your right to the source code... it really depends on what your contract is with the developer.  The BSD license does not force developers to release any derivative work (i.e. work based on the BSD licensed code) to be also released under open source, and/or make the source code available.  So you can view the source code of Silverstripe from its website (Silverstripe being open source), but your developer does not need to make the source code of her code and/or any modification she might have made on Silverstripe available to anyone.  She could even sell Silverstipe code unchanged should she want to.

So whether you should have access to your developer's code is really governed by what agreement you have with the developer regarding her work i.e. whether you own all the IP produced by the developer including the source code.